# Derivation of path equation, how to derive $$ r''= - \frac{L^2}{m^2}u^2 \frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2 } $$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion

So specifically I don't know how to go from $r'$ to $r''$. If we start with $r'$, where the substitution $r=u^{-1}$ is used.

$$ r'= - \frac{L}{m} \frac{du}{d\theta } $$

$$ (1): r''= - \frac{L^2}{m^2}u^2 \frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2 } $$

I start with differentiating $r'$ w.r.t $t$:

$$\ddot{r}=\frac{d}{dt}\dot{r}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(-u^{-2}\right)\dot{u} -\ u^{-2}\frac{d}{dt}\dot{u}$$

Which I find

$$ =u^{-2}{\dot{\theta}}^2\left(2u^{-1}\left(\frac{du}{d\theta}\right)^2-\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}\right)$$

And I don't know how to carry on to find equation $(1)$

Comment: You seem to use $'$ and $\dot{}$ interchangeably for time derivatives; you'd be better using only the latter, and denoting $\theta$ derivatives with $'$. Hint, in such notation: $\dot{r}=-u^{-2}\dot{u}=-hu'$ with $h:=L/m$ the _specific angular momentum_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that with $L$ you mean the orbital angular momentum. Hence, in polar coordinates, $L=mr^2\dot{\theta}=mr^2\frac{d\theta}{dt}$. Moreover, for a function $f(\theta(t))$ we have
$$ \frac{d}{dt}f(\theta(t))=\frac{df}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt} $$
Hence:

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\dot{r}=-\frac{L}{m}\frac{d}{dt}\frac{du}{d\theta}=-\frac{L}{m}\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}\frac{d\theta}{dt}=-\frac{L}{m}\frac{L}{mr^2}\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}=-\frac{L^2}{m^2r^2}\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}$$

which is what you want if you define $u=1/r$.